# speech:syncrecognize The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request

Tags: json, api, curl, speech

i test google speech api, first:

i try example as google demo, succeed.

```js
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "sample_rate": 16000,
      "language_code": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
     "uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}
```

server return:

```js
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
          "confidence": 0.98267895
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

then, i upload my local voice sample, but failed：

```js
  {
      "config": {
          "encoding":"FLAC",
          "sample_rate": 44100,
          "language_code": "en-US"
      },
      "audio": {
          "content":"ZkxhQwAAACIQABAAAA1rABd1CsRC8AABvXRcP4VKHGyzkYLpo......."
      }
    }
```

i have no idea about the error ： The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload your file on google storage and pass the link of the file instead of the content ("URI" instead of "Content") and see if that works. If your file is longer than 1 minute, you'd have to use asynchronous API and encoding as LINEAR16